# Cannot resolve DefaultManifestParser after gradle plugin upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I'm trying to compile [AndroidCaldavSyncAdapter](https://github.com/ennswi/AndroidCaldavSyncAdapater) project in Android Studio. It has even worked before, but after upgrade gradle plugin version from `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0` to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0` it stopped working. Now I'm getting this error:

```
  Error:(34, 0) A problem occurred evaluating project ':ACalDAV'.
```

and
    `cannot resolve symbol 'builder'` in

```
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser
```

Here is the `build.grade` file:

```
import com.android.builder.core.DefaultManifestParser

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: '../config/quality/quality.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "de.we.acaldav"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        multiDexEnabled true

        def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser()
        versionName = manifestParser.getVersionName(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    }

    signingConfigs {
        //noinspection GroovyMissingReturnStatement
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('myKeyAlias') &&
                    project.hasProperty('myStoreFile') &&
                    project.hasProperty('myStorePassword') &&
                    project.hasProperty('myKeyPassword')) {
                keyAlias = myKeyAlias
                storeFile = file(myStoreFile)
                storePassword = myStorePassword
                keyPassword = myKeyPassword
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFile 'proguard-project.txt'
        }

        debug {
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            applicationIdSuffix = ".debug"
            //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
            versionNameSuffix = "-DEBUG"
        }

        //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.each { output ->
                output.outputFile = new File(output.outputFile.parent, output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk"))
            }
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile  'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.0'
    compile  'backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1'
    compile  'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
    compile  'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    compile  'org.mnode.ical4j:ical4j:1.0.6'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
    }
}
```

I have tried invalidate caches but this hasn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That happens, because the signature of `DefaultManifestParser` has changed: now it expects `manifestFile` as an argument.

In Android Gradle Plugin [version 1.5.0](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/com.android.tools.build/builder/1.5.0/src-html/com/android/builder/core/DefaultManifestParser.html) there is no explicitly provided a constructor for `DefaultManifestParser`, which means there is a empty constructor. That results expression `def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser()` to be executed normally.

In Android Gradle Plugin [version 2.2.0](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/com.android.tools.build/builder/2.2.0/src-html/com/android/builder/core/DefaultManifestParser.html) the signature of constructor has changed to following:

```
public DefaultManifestParser(@NonNull File manifestFile)
```

Which means, that following changes in `build.gradle` file should be performed:

```
def manifestParser = new DefaultManifestParser(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
versionName = manifestParser.getVersionName()
```

Comment: I would highly suggested reading this for updating to Gradle Plugin 3.0: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html some other syntax like altering the output file name also has changed.